# How to compare two tables in data studio

Tags: comparison, looker-studio

I have two tables in data studio: [image: tables]

I'm asking the user to select two dates to compare two weeks. This way, we can see the two weeks' data side by side. However, I also want to see the percentages of change based on vendor. Is there a way to show this? Or how can I improve the comparison method ?

note: vendor name field is not fixed. it can change for every week.

Comment: i can do it with sql. you can see detail in this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036254/big-query-compare-two-weeks-data)

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio provides a way to compare current date with previous one, but the comparison parameter will be fixed (eg. "current week vs previous week", "current month vs 2 months ago"). That means you won't be able to drop a selector for your users.

With this feature you to select the current date (or a range of dates) and it will always compare to the period you choose in design view. (I usually select the option "previous period", so if the user select a week, the comparison will be with the previous week; if the user select a month, the comparison will be with the previous month).

To achieve this, just check [this entry in the documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9272806).

Another limitation is that it will always display the difference between current value and previous value (delta).  Currently, you can't change this behavior.