# big query compare two weeks' data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, compare

i have a table in big query. like this:

```
date(week)   vendor_name     value
2021-11-14   rick            8000
2021-11-14   rose            7000
2021-11-14   axel            6500
2021-11-14   boris           6000
2021-11-14   cliff           5500
2021-11-07   rose            9500
2021-11-07   axel            8750
2021-11-07   rick            4000
2021-11-07   dean            3500
2021-11-07   evan            3000
.....
```

The date column indicates the start date of each week. The vendor_name column shows the top 5 selling vendors that week. The value column shows the total sales amount. the top vendors of each week may be different. Expected output:

```
date(week)  vendor_name      value   previous_date  previous_top_vendors  previous_value   change
2021-11-14   rick            8000    2021-11-07     rose                  9500             -%26
2021-11-14   rose            7000    2021-11-07     axel                  8750             -25
2021-11-14   axel            6500    2021-11-07     rick                  4000             %100
2021-11-14   boris           6000    2021-11-07     dean                  3500             Null
2021-11-14   cliff           5500    2021-11-07     evan                  3000             Null
```

After receiving the latest date, the previous week's data will arrive. for these two weeks, sellers will be compared and their percentage of change will be shown in the column called change.

Note: The rank of vendors may change every week. A new vendor can be ranked (In this case, it should appear as Null in the "change" column)

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM (select*from `table.top20_vendor` where date = '2021-11-14'),
(select date as previous_date, vendor_name as previous_top_vendors,value as previous_value 
from `table.top20_vendor` where date ='2021-11-07')
```

but the output not true:

```
date(week)  vendor_name      value   previous_date  previous_top_vendors  previous_value
2021-11-14   rick            8000    2021-11-07     rose                  9500   
2021-11-14   rick            8000    2021-11-07     axel                  8750   
2021-11-14   rick            8000    2021-11-07     rick                  4000
2021-11-14   rick            8000    2021-11-07     dean                  3500             
2021-11-14   rick            8000    2021-11-07     evan                  3000
```

also, I have no idea how to calculate the "change" column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did first was to get the top 5 values of the desired week, and I used the following query:

```
select * from
(
select date, vendor_name, value , row_number() over(partition by date order by value desc) as rn
from `project.dataset.table`
)A
where rn<=5 and date='2021-11-14'
```

Then, what needs to be done is to make the change of the values. For that, you need to use a percentage formula and join these weeks’ value by the name of the vendors.

```
 SELECT prev_week.rn,((curr_week.value-prev_week.value)/prev_week.value)*100 as change FROM curr_week right join  prev_week on curr_week.vendor_name = prev_week.vendor_name
```

Consider the approach below:

```
with curr_week as(
select * from
(
select date, vendor_name, value , row_number() over(partition by date order by value desc) as rn
from `project.dataset.table`
)A
where rn<=5 and date='2021-11-14'
),
prev_week as (
   select * from
(
select date, vendor_name, value , row_number() over(partition by date order by value desc) as rn
from `project.dataset.table`
)A
where rn<=5 and date='2021-11-07'
),
changes as(
   SELECT prev_week.rn,((curr_week.value-prev_week.value)/prev_week.value)*100 as change FROM curr_week right join  prev_week on curr_week.vendor_name = prev_week.vendor_name
)
 
select curr_week.date,
curr_week.vendor_name,
curr_week.value,
prev_week.date as previous_date,
prev_week.vendor_name as previous_top_vendors,
prev_week.value as previous_value,
changes.change
from curr_week left join prev_week on curr_week.rn = prev_week.rn
left join changes on prev_week.rn = changes.rn
```

The results I get are as follows:

[image]

Comment: its working. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand your logic you have for change in terms of which records you're comparing against, but this should get you most of the way there in terms of comparing the vendors and their values between weeks:

```
with sample_data as (
    select '2021-11-14' as week,   'rick' as vendor_name,            8000 as value UNION ALL 
    select '2021-11-14' as week,   'rose' as vendor_name,            7000 as value UNION ALL 
    select '2021-11-14' as week,   'axel' as vendor_name,            6500 as value UNION ALL 
    select '2021-11-14' as week,   'boris' as vendor_name,           6000 as value UNION ALL 
    select '2021-11-14' as week,   'cliff' as vendor_name,           5500 as value UNION ALL 
    select '2021-11-07' as week,   'rose' as vendor_name,            9500 as value UNION ALL 
    select '2021-11-07' as week,   'axel' as vendor_name,            8750 as value UNION ALL 
    select '2021-11-07' as week,   'rick' as vendor_name,            4000 as value UNION ALL 
    select '2021-11-07' as week,   'dean' as vendor_name,            3500 as value UNION ALL 
    select '2021-11-07' as week,   'evan' as vendor_name,            3000 as value
)
,
ranked_data as (
    select dense_rank() over (order by week desc) week_rank
    , rank() over (partition by week order by value) vendor_rank
    , *
from sample_data
)
select curr_week.week
    , curr_week.vendor_name
    , curr_week.value
    , prev_week.week as previous_week
    , prev_week.vendor_name as previous_top_vendors
    , prev_week.value as previous_value
    , 
from ranked_data curr_week
left join ranked_data prev_week
 on curr_week.vendor_rank=prev_week.vendor_rank
 and prev_week.week_rank=2
where curr_week.week_rank=1
order by 3 desc
```

Ultimately I think you'll need a lead or lag depending on the calculation in the middle step.  If you can elaborate a bit more I may be able to add the component in for change.